# Вывод сообщения в об ошибке в консоль

Tags: linux, debian, консоль

Подскажите, не могу понять что за сообщение регулярно появляется в консоли текущего пользователя:

```
Message from syslogd@sde391 at Nov 28 00:23:03 ...
 kernel:[14019442.496028] unregister_netdevice: waiting for eth0 to become free. Usage count = 1

Message from syslogd@sde391 at Nov 28 00:23:34 ...
 kernel:[14019472.860028] unregister_netdevice: waiting for eth0 to become free. Usage count = 1

Message from syslogd@sde391 at Nov 28 00:24:24 ...
 kernel:[14019523.260025] unregister_netdevice: waiting for eth0 to become free. Usage count = 1
```

Может кто встречался с похожей проблеммой?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема связана с запущенными LXC контейнерами. Перезапуск контейнера помог решить проблему. Почему возникает и как локализовать конкретный контейнер пока выяснить не удалось.